# Phalcon two single routes

Tags: php, routes, phalcon

## I have a problem. I have two routes:

```
$router->add('/news/{alias:[a-z\-]+}(/?)', array(
      'module' => 'frontend',
      'controller' => 'news',
      'action' => 'view',
      'news_id' => 1,
      'lang' => 'md',
))->setName('news_view_short_e'); //=> /news/282334-alias-news
```

## AND route => /news/index/:

```
$router->add('/{lang:[' . $langsDefined . ']{2}+}/{controller:[a-z]{3,50}+}(/?)', array(
     'module' => 'frontend',
     'controller' => 2,
     'action' => 'index',
     'lang' => 1,
))->setName('default_module_lang');
```

When I use these routes. site.com/news/index not working. But if I remove route with alias. Route site.com/news/index working good. How I can resolve conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it matches your "index" as alias parameter too, so first rule wins. There's no magic solution other than just fixing your regex or reordering your routes.

Reversing your routes order will bring a new problem though, reversely because it will also match the controller instead of your alias.

I prefer to stick with the default routing, and mount a router group here's my router right now:

```
//From my config
        'router' => array(
            'defaults' => array(
                'namespace' => 'My\\Default\\Namespace\\Controllers',
                'module' => 'frontend',
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'notFound' => array(
                'controller' => 'errors',
                'action' => 'notFound'
            )
        ),

// From my service
$router = new Router();
$router->removeExtraSlashes(true);
$router->setDefaults($this->config->router->defaults->toArray()?: $this->defaults);
$router->notFound($this->config->router->notFound->toArray()?: $this->notFound);
$router->mount(new ModuleRoute($this->getDefaults(), true));


class ModuleRoute extends RouterGroup
{
public $default = false;

public function __construct($paths = null, $default = false)
{
    $this->default = $default;
    parent::__construct($paths);
}

public function initialize()
{
    $path = $this->getPaths();
    $routeKey = '/' . $path['module'];
    $this->setPrefix('/{locale:([a-z]{2,3}([\_\-][[:alnum:]]{1,8})?)}' . ($this->default ? null : $routeKey));
    $this->add( '/:params', array(
        'namespace' => $path['namespace'],
        'module' => $path['module'],
        'controller' => $path['controller'],
        'action' => $path['action'],
        'params' => 3
    ))->setName($routeKey);
    $this->add( '/:controller/:params', array(
        'namespace' => $path['namespace'],
        'module' => $path['module'],
        'controller' => 3,
        'action' => $path['action'],
        'params' => 4
    ))->setName($routeKey);
    $this->add( '/:controller/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/:params', array(
        'namespace' => $path['namespace'],
        'module' => $path['module'],
        'controller' => 3,
        'action' => 4,
        'params' => 5
    ))->setName($routeKey);
    $this->add( '/:controller/:int', array(
        'namespace' => $path['namespace'],
        'module' => $path['module'],
        'controller' => 3,
        'id' => 4,
    ))->setName($routeKey);
}
}
```